# Unity3d: How to Integrate Parse in Unity for iOs Builds?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, analytics

I'm trying to integrate parse analytics into my app. I'm using unity, and inside the editor Parse works fine, but when I build for iOS I don´t receive any errors... however Parse is not receiving data from my iOS device.

I imported from the Asset Store all the parse files, am I missing something?.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your application to Parse? You need to specify your Application ID and .NET Key. It may be a good idea to try the [quickstart](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/unity/existing) they have on their website, rather than the Unity Asset Store. More details on how those credentials are used can be found in the [docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/unity/guide#security-client-vs-server).